# How to install Ubuntu on Arm Lenovo Ideapad 4 4g Snapdragon 8c?

Tags: arm

I am trying to install Ubuntu arm on a Lenovo 4 4g Snapdragon 8c (not 8cx) laptop but am experiencing a problem.

After choosing to install a black screen is shown with a dash top left then it reboots without every loading a graphical installation screen.

I have turned secure boot off, disabled hibernate, and more but the same behaviour occurs.

The black screen will say "Booting command list" then it just restarts.

I phoned Lenovo customer support previously and they told me it should work but they did not test it.

Specs:
QualcommSnapdragon 8c8x Kryo490 8 -Kryo490@2.45GHz - LPDDR4x Qualcomm Adreno

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, you left out this critical detail.

Comment: I have tried a number of them.

22.10. 23.04.

And I have tried Arch too.

Same behaviour.

After choosing to install the screen goes black then the machine reboots or it shows 'Booting command list'.



Comment: Booting command list is not a Ubuntu action or term. Maybe ask in a Lenovo forum.

Comment: That must have been Arch.

My apologies for confusion as I tried a numbe of variations.